# How to check http:// in xml formate with xslt

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

Hi i have three seneriao

one is if i received to with `"/"` tag relative path in xml than i check to this it's working .

two is if i received to with out `"/"` tag relative path in xml than how to check this. (how to check if it's come form `http` in xml )

```
<xsl:when test="ploverridelink">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="substring(ploverridelink,1,1)='/'">
            <xsl:variable name="newploverridelink" select="ploverridelink"/>
            <xsl:variable name="finalploverridelink" select="concat('http://rohitazad.com',$newploverridelink)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$finalploverridelink"/>

        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="substring(ploverridelink,1,1)='markets'">
            <xsl:variable name="newploverridelink_2" select="ploverridelink"/>
            <xsl:variable name="finalploverridelink_2" select="concat('http://rohitazad.com',$newploverridelink_2)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$finalploverridelink_2"/>

        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="ploverridelink"/>

        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:when>
```

My XML format tag is with relative path
  `<ploverridelink>kumarsec.html</ploverridelink>`

My XML format tag is with relative path with `"/"`

```
<ploverridelink>/kumarsec.html</ploverridelink>
```

My XML formate tag is with absolute path

```
<ploverridelink>http://www.rohitazad.com/kumarsec.html</ploverridelink>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you'd like to do? Perhaps you can use the `starts-with()` function?

Comment: `substring(ploverridelink,1,1)='markets'` does not seem to make sense, the substring will only return one character which should never match `'markets'` - the `starts-with()` function from @potame's comment seems to be worth a look for you

Answer (score 0):

after some time i search to google i found a solution .

```
<xsl:when test="ploverridelink">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="substring(ploverridelink,1,1)='/'">
                            <xsl:variable name="newoverridelink" select="ploverridelink"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="finaloverridelink" select="concat('http://www.rohitazad.com',$newoverridelink)"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$finaloverridelink"/>
                        </xsl:when>

                        <xsl:when test="contains(ploverridelink,'http://www.rohitazad.com')"><xsl:value-of select="ploverridelink"/></xsl:when>

                        <xsl:otherwise>http://www.rohitazad.com/<xsl:value-of select="ploverridelink"/></xsl:otherwise>

                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:when>
            <xsl:value-of select="ploverridelink"/>

        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:when>
```